# License-Maven-Plugin equivalent in ant

Tags: maven, ant, mojo

In my `Java EE` project we are using `ANT` as the build tool.
Is there an equivalent for [License Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/index.html) in ANT World?

Comment: Googling found the following: http://code.google.com/p/licensecollector/